# kotlin object (local final class) not serializable

Tags: kotlin, spring-rabbit

For Some reason, I need to construct an object in kotlin like below and need to send to rabbitMQ using rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend.  But when I do that, I get an error

```
       var myObject = object {
            var name = "Object Name"
            var description = "Object Description"
        }
```

Error

`SimpleMessageConverter only supports String, byte[] and Serializable payloads`

What should I do to make `myObject` as `Serializable`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your object is not Serializable. To fix try:

```
var myObject = object : Serializable {
    var name = "Object Name"
    var description = "Object Description"
}
```

Keep in mind, that for consistent deserialization in case of class changes you need to declare constant `serialVersionUID` at companion object, but they are not available to local class.

Comment: This clarifies ! Thanks a lot